# Decode LoRaWAN data GPS tracker Moko LW001-BG The Things Network

Tags: iot, lora, lorawan

I am new to LoRa. I tried to connect my Lora GW & GPS tracer LW001-BG to The Things Network, and it successfully connected to TTN. But how to convert or decode the data from the GPS to latlong format?

Here is [the documentation](http://doc.mokotechnology.com/index.php?s=/2&page_id=143). I receive data format like this `02 01 56 F8 0B 45 F4 29 32 46` and I need to convert/decode it to a readable format.

Thanks, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The payload of the message is in bytes 3-6 (for the latitude) and 7-10 (for the longitude). The first two bytes indicate how many packages there are (two) and which the current one is (the first).

The four bytes represent a [32 bit floating point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format); in your example this is 2239.5210 for the latitude. This means 22 degrees, 39 minutes, and 31.26 seconds (which is the fraction times sixty).

You can see this in an [on-line converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html): As the byte order is lowest byte first, you need to reverse it, convert it to binary, and then check the checkboxes in the binary representation:

`54 F8 0B 45` becomes `45 0B F8 56` or binary

`01000101000010111111100001010110`

Here the first bit is the sign, followed by 8 bits of the exponent and 23 bits mantissa. The decimal representation is 2239.52099609 and you discard all digits after the fourth to get 2239.5210 (with rounding).

Depending on how you process this data, you might be able to simply cast this to a `float` variable, as they are generally following the 32 bit IEEE 754 standard.